# iOS turn off Fade-in effects?

Tags: iphone, ios, accessibility, setup

<sup>(*Not talking about* **S**ettings ➙ **A**ccessibility ➙ **R**educe **M**otion ➙ **R**educe **M**otion)</sup>

Is there a way, on iOS (10+) and specifically iPhone (6+), to suppress the Fade-in/Mixing effects?

Especially pressing the <kbd>HOME</kbd> button to go back from an app to home, there is a small delay to which is added the fade-in effect.

I don't mind a fade-in effect, as long as it's barely noticeable, but with newer iOSes, an iPhone gets slower and slower. The 6+ is not that bad, yet, but still, some effects are annoying.

Suppressing obtrusive effects to get a more responsive device would be great!

Comment: Not sure you can; have you asked apple support :D?

Comment: Is it correct that you have an iPhone 6 Plus – not an iPhone 6s Plus – and that it's running the latest iOS 10.2 or 10.2.1?

Comment: @oa That's correct!

Answer (score 1):

### How to remove the animation when closing an app

Please note: I tested this with an **iPhone 5s running iOS 10.2.1**. It **should work with the iPhone 6** / iPhone 6 Plus as well, but not with newer devices (iPhone SE/6s/6s Plus/7/7 Plus). Also, the animations will be back as soon as you reboot your device.

Part 1/2: Prepare

1. Open [this picture](http://www.oliveranderson.de/temp/black_pixel.png) in Safari.
2. Press the "Share" button on the bottom and tap "**Save Image**".
3. Go to Settings > Wallpaper > **Choose a New Wallpaper** > All Photos.
4. **Select the new image** (black pixel).
5. Tap "Set" > "Set Both".
6. Tap "Choose" > "Wallpaper" to go back.

---

Part 2/2: Crash

Now you need to crash the process that's responsible for the smooth animations. You need to **repeat the process below about 10-14 times**.

1. Tap on the lock screen preview (on the left).
2. Tap "Set"
3. Tap on the home screen preview (on the right).
4. Tap "Set".

You can verify that animations were disabled by pressing the home button. There will be no animation at all.

If you still the usual animation, go back to the wallpaper settings and repeat part 2 a few more times.

.

Please let me know if this works for your iPhone 5s or iPhone 6 / iPhone 6 Plus.